# Given a List get all the combinations of tuples without duplicated results

Tags: python, list, tuples, combinations

I have a list=[1,2,3,4]
And I only want to receive tuple results for like all the positions in a matrix, so it would be

```
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4)
```

I've seen several codes that return all the combinations but i don't know how to restrict it only to the tuples or how to add the (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `[(i, j) for i in lst for j in lst]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a double loop. A generator makes it easy to use

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]

def matrix(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(len(lst)):
            yield lst[i], lst[j]

output = [t for t in matrix(lst)]

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do this for making pairs of all symbols in the list

```py
tuple_pairs = [(r,c) for r in lst for c in lst]
```

If you have instead some maximum row/colum numbers `max_row` and `max_col` you could avoid making the `lst=[1,2,3,4]` and instead;

```py
tuple_pairs = [(r,c) for r in range(1,max_row+1) for c in range(1,max_col+1)]
```

But that's assuming that the `lst`'s goal was to be `= range(1, some_num)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get all possible combinations of an iterable object. `product` is roughly equivalent to nested for-loops with depth specified by the keyword parameter `repeat`. It returns an iterator.

```
from itertools import product

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]

combos = product(lst, repeat=2)
combos = list(combos) # cast to list
print(*combos, sep=' ')
```

Diagonal terms can be found in a single loop (without any extra imports)

```
repeat = 2
diagonal = [(i,)*repeat for i in lst]
print(*diagonal sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using list comprehension.

```
lst=[1,2,3,4]

out=[(i,i) for i in lst]

print(out)
```

**Output**:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
```